# How to get weeks between two dates

Tags: php, datetime, datediff, dateinterval

How do I get a reliable date diff in weeks?

So far I've got

```
<?php
$a = new DateTime('2010-09-01');
$b = new DateTime();

$c = $a->diff($b);
```

Now I get a DateInterval with years, months and so on, but as far as I know a year does not have exactly 52 weeks and so doesn't a month have exactly 4 weeks.

Any suggestions how to get the real, reliable week count?

Comment: week numbers or really weeks? Because really weeks you can use timestamp, and divide that by seconds/minutes/hours/days/7

Comment: Yeah thanks that's it, I just made it too complicated for myself again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can Count the days between your two dates and divide by 7?

Comment: As easy as that. why do I always overcomplicate situations? :) thanks! (I will accept as soon as I am allowed)

Comment: It is not correct, example startDate is 01/02/2020 and endDate is 10/02/2020, you devide by 7 and see 2 weeks only, but it should be 3

Comment: There is 9 days between startDate  01/02/2020 and endDate 10/02/2020. Should give you 1 week.

Answer (score 2):

get the difference in days, and divide it by 7? or, if you are using older versions of PHP, get the differences in hours/minutes/seconds, and calculate it accordingly..